# Migrating from Windows 2000 (Server) to Ubuntu 14.10 (Server)

Tags: server, windows, virtualbox, printing, file-sharing

I'm BRAND SPANKING new to Linux.  I'd really appreciate any help I can get with this.

I've been tasked to upgrade a dying Windows 2000 box that acts as a file and print server.  Sounds easy, right?  There's only 2 problems with doing it:

A. This is NOT a Domain Controller
B. It's not running Active Directory

I have a considerable amount of users (over 300) and files (I'm still trying to figure that out) and I need the easiest way to transfer everything over.  I downloaded the latest server release of Ubuntu and I'm running it on VirtualBox on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Box.  Considering those two facts I outlined, what's the easiest way to do this without ripping out whatever remaining hair I have on my head?

Comment: Totally honest half-stupid question: Why wouldn't you just migrate from Win2k to Win Server 2k8 or 2k12 to keep everything on the same level of compatibility without having to learn how to maintain a system you're unfamiliar with.  Upgrading is not *that* hard, I don't believe.

Comment: Believe me, no question is stupid. I actually appreciate it.

The short answer: I inherited this problem...I have to work with what I've got.

Comment: ***Some advice:*** You need to be using **14.04 LTS** (not 14.10). There is no plausible reason to be trying to run this on a client-VM under **Win Server 2012 R2**. If you are learning, start with a standalone Ubuntu 14.04 server (on a small standalone). Longterm, consider using VMware on your (larger) server/rack, alongside Win Server 2012 R2 (on a VM).

Comment: Regarding "this is not DC, not running AD", I am not exactly sure what "this" means, old w2k or your fresh ubuntu install. Why did you tell us about this? What is a problem to solve?

Comment: THIS refers to the Win2k box. The problem is I can't just migrate to Windows Server without the 2k box being a domain controller and running active directory.  I'm seeing if I can do the transfer to Ubuntu instead and if so, how to do it.  Sorry if I wasn't more specific.

Comment: OMG!  You need an old fart to do something like this!  `net user /domain >>c:\temp\Everyone.TXT` is a start, but then you have the `cacls` etc.  I think, you'd better ask the export kind of stuff on http://superuser.com/ and then come back here to ask how to import it...  Drop a note @Fabby if you have no clue what I'm talking about.